# Regex to find string in log file and separate string into parts

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

I'm very new to regex, but I've done my research enough to throw this together. Unfortunately I've hit a block. I'll be using this regex with PHP preg_match to parse a few server logs and return specific strings like the example in "My String".

My Regex:

```
\b([0-9\:]+)\s\"ANTIHAKE\sFOUND:\s+(.*?)\s\(([^)]+)\)\s+REASON:\s+(.*?)\s+\(([^)]+)\)"
```

My string:

```
15:34:51 "ANTIHAKE FOUND:  Kevin (106534790)  REASON:  Global Var  (Monky_hax_toggled)"
```

Ultimately my goal here is to pull out a total of 5 variables:
Time - "15:34:51"
Name - "Kevin"
UID - "106534790"
Reason - "Global Var"
Specific Reason - "Monky_hax_toggled"

A specific problem I'm having is capturing the reason. I just can't seem to figure out how to capture "Global Var" as one string, whitespace included. Would someone kindly help me out?

Thanks!
Jon

Comment: Let me just add that all 5 variables will be dynamic.
""ANTIHAKE FOUND:" and "REASON:" will always be static, as will the time format.

Comment: Your regex is working fine already. See here http://viper-7.com/WcgfQn

Comment: I must be up for too long, thanks for clarifying. Amazingly fast response too! You're awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removing the \s+ after (.*?) seems ok to me-:

```
\b([0-9\:]+)\s\"ANTIHAKE\sFOUND:\s+(.*?)\s\(([^)]+)\)\s+REASON:\s+(.*?)\(([^)]+)\)
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})\s+"ANTIHAKE FOUND:\s+([^(]+)\s+\(([0-9]+)\)\s+REASON:\s+([^(]+)\s+\(([^)]+)\)"
```

Keep in mind that the regexp is tailored to your example.

Comment: Thanks, but according to cryptic my regex is already working. Thanks for the super quick response tho.